# DownloadManager Deletes File On Completion

Tags: android, download-manager

I have an app that downloads files using Android's [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to a folder on the external file storage (SD card).  This normally works fine, but there are some sources that cause the DownloadManager to trash the file when it finishes downloading it.  A good example of a source file is:

http://traffic.libsyn.com/hdtvpodcast/HDTV-2012-06-01.mp3

It looks like maybe the problem is only with files from libsyn.com, but I'm not positive.  I've looked around for ways to change how DownloadManager handles saving files, but can't find any options in the class.

This is where I enqueue the URL for download:

```
request = new Request(Uri.parse(currUrl));
external = Uri.fromFile(externalFile);
request.setDestinationUri(external);
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
request.setNotificationVisibility(
    DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
currDownloadId = dm.enqueue(request);
```

The file locations are created using this:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
    File.separator + "Podcatcher" + File.separator + "Feeds" + File.separator + 
    [int] + File.separator + [int] + [string extension];
```

Which turns out to be something like this when I query DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME column from DownloadManager:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Podcatcher/Feeds/19/225.mp3
```

Most of the files are fine and persist after download, but not in this case.  Any ideas about how I can force DownloadManager to leave the file after it is downloaded?

EDIT: I neglected to mention that when I use the standalone Download Manager when downloading this file from a browser that it reports failed at the end of the download.  Perhaps my only solution is to download it from scratch, without DownloadManager?

Comment: Maybe try `dm.query()` and check `COLUMN_STATUS` and `COLUMN_REASON` columns for possible errors?

Comment: I'm doing that each time I check the status and update the database accordingly.  I don't see anything other than 0 unfortunately.  Due to  this, what seems like a bug in DownloadManager to me, I think I'm going to have to ditch using it to ensure everything is downloaded.  I haven't tried it from scratch yet, but I'll see if that has the same failure at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 0 for reason.  Status is 8 (successful) when the download "completes".

Answer (score 1):

try please followed code  - worked for me:

```
request.setMimeType(application/octet-stream);
```